# How to get the Website link using php code

Tags: php

i want to use a code in php which will get the website link automatic in  link tab

For ex 
if i put that code in www.example.com it will show the www.example.com
or if i put that code in www.example-1.com it will show the www.example-1.com
without making any changes again and again in code .

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks @sougata & @Abdulla

i have tried this and it works

```
<a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>"><img src="logo"></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `SERVER_NAME`

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
?>
```

**Output**

```
www.example.com
```

---

Try `HTTP_HOST`

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];;
?>
```

**Output**

```
www.example.com
```

[`$_SERVER` in php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and [PHP `$_SERVER` in W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp)